# UIPageViewController - Don't allow to move if no pages

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

In my app I do not want it to be possible to drag if there is no pages before and/or after.

See the images below.

I do not want it to be able to move if there is no pages before or after the current page. No matter how much you drag, I want it to stay still like the second image, if there is no pages before and/or after.

**How it is now when dragging:**

[image]

**How I want it to be when no pages before and/or after when dragging:**

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

**Disable bounce effect in `UIPageViewController`:**

```
for (UIView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews ) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *scroll = (UIScrollView *)view;
            scroll.bounces = NO;
        }
}
```

Comment: Does not work - disables the pan gesture on the page view controller.